# JSON jQuery issue: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, json

I am writing a jQuery call to retrieve JSON data from the memegenerator.net API.  However, using the code below, I get a *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :* error whenever I test it in Chrome.  I tried removing the callback=? and that threw another error.

Whenever I go to the URL directly, it comes back fine.

JSLint in JSFiddle declares the returned JSON as valid.

Any ideas on how to make this call successful?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://version1.api.memegenerator.net/Instances_Select_ByNew?languageCode=en&pageIndex=0&pageSize=12&urlName=Insanity-Wolf?callback=?',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
            console.log('Success!');
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('Uh Oh!');
        }
    });
});​      
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cross domain error. You cannot request things from a domain other than yours with ajax without either using `jsonp` or a proxy script on your server. (If using php it will be a [cURL request](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php))

Look for jsonp on the [ajax docs page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

cURL request:

```
$cURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://version1.api.memegenerator.net/Instances_Select_ByNew?languageCode=en&pageIndex=0&pageSize=12&urlName=Insanity-Wolf');
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
echo $output;
```

Comment: it seems memegenerator doesn't provide jsonp or CORS headers (which would allow cross-domain ajax to work normally).

Comment: so you will need to call a script on your server which makes a cURL request to that url and then return that.

Comment: I'm not the op, just wanted to point out that *You cannot request things from a domain other than yours with ajax* is wrong  :P

Comment: umm did you stop reading my answer? That's what I have? And haha shows you much attention im paying....

Comment: No I mean, what you have is wrong. You *can* request things from a domain other than yours with ajax, without using a proxy or jsonp.

Comment: hmmm do you have a link of an example. Everytime I've done it it hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol. You need jsonp.

Answer (score 0):

That api either doesn't support JSONP, or it is looking for a different callback param than `callback`.

also, your url should be

```
http://version1.api.memegenerator.net/Instances_Select_ByNew?languageCode=en&pageIndex=0&pageSize=12&urlName=Insanity-Wolf&callback=?
```

note the `&` instead of `?`

also, dataType should be `"jsonp"`